# drag and drop images from `dropbox` account to html canvas - `not working in chrome`

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, dropbox, fabricjs, same-origin-policy

This code is to drag images from image gallery and drop inside canvas (fabric.js is used) and also drag and drop images from dropbox account which is opend in another tab. This works fine in firefox, I can drag images from my drop box account and drop in inside canvas. But not in chrome. `e.dataTransfer.getData("Text")` gives an empty value in chrome. I thought it's a problem of `same-origin-policy` and tried a lot to fix it. But no luck. Please help me to get a work around for this.

```
    function handleDrop(e) {    
   e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
   // handle local images   
   if(e.dataTransfer.files.length > 0){

        var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

            // Only process image files.
            if (f.type.match('image.*')) {            
                // Read the File objects in this FileList.
                var reader = new FileReader();
                // listener for the onload event
                reader.onload = function(evt) {
                    // create img element
                    var img = document.createElement('img');
                    img.src= evt.target.result;                        

                    // put image on canvas
                    var newImage = new fabric.Image(img, {
                        width: img.width,
                        height: img.height,
                        // Set the center of the new object based on the event coordinates relative to the canvas container.
                        left: e.layerX,
                        top: e.layerY
                    });
                    canvas.add(newImage);
                };
               // Read in the image file as a data URL.
               reader.readAsDataURL(f);
            }
        }
    }  
   // handle dropbox images
    else{        
       var img = e.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
       console.log(img);
       var img = e.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
       if (img.indexOf('jpg')>0 ||img.indexOf('png')>0){           
           var temp = '<img draggable="true" src="'+img+'" width="250" height="250"></img>';
           $('#before').append(temp);
           var i = document.querySelector('img[src="'+img+'"]');
           console.log('i: ',i);
           var nI = new fabric.Image(i,{
           width: i.width,
           height:i.height,
           left:e.layerX,
           top:e.layerY
           });
           canvas.add(nI); 
        }
        }    
    return false;
}
```